# jQuery when each is completed, trigger function

Tags: jquery, each

how do start a function like redirecting to a new page when .each is done looping my elements?
this is my current code:

```
$('#tabCurrentFriends > .dragFriend').each(function(){ 
    var friendId = $(this).data('rowid');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", url: "../../page/newtab.php", data: "action=new&tabname=" + tabname + "&bid=" + brugerid + "&fid=" + friendid,
        complete: function(data){
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: When it's done *looping* or done making AJAX requests?

Comment: when its done looping the .each function, say i have 6 elements it has to the ajax function with and when the 6 elements have been 'ajaxed' then it does something

Comment: the looping finishes almost instantaneously.  the ajax requests is what takes time, you have to wait for the responses.  Once a response is received, the complete function is executed.  Study the term 'asynchronous' - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `$.when()`/`$.then()` to redirect your users after all the AJAX requests are done:

```
//create array to hold deferred objects
var XHRs = [];
$('#tabCurrentFriends > .dragFriend').each(function(){  
    var friendId = $(this).data('rowid'); 

    //push a deferred object onto the `XHRs` array
    XHRs.push($.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", url: "../../page/newtab.php", data: "action=new&tabname=" + tabname + "&bid=" + brugerid + "&fid=" + friendid, 
        complete: function(data){ 
        } 
    })); 
}); 

//run a function when all deferred objects resolve
$.when(XHRs).then(function (){
    window.location = 'http://stackoverflow.com/';
});
```

**Edit** - to use `when` with an array, `apply` must be used:

```
$.when.apply(null, XHRs).then(function () {
    window.location = 'http://stackoverflow.com/';
});
```

jQuery AJAX requests create deffered objects that resolve when their complete function fires. This code stores those deffered objects in an array and when they all resolved the function within `.then()` is run.

Docs:

- `$.when()`: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when
- `$.then()`: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/

Comment: what does the XHRs variable do ?

Comment: @Flaashing It is an array of deferred objects which resolve when the AJAX call they are associated with finishes. `$.when()` waits for all of the deferred objects to resolve in the XHRs array (meaning all the AJAX calls are finished) and runs the function in `.then()` .

Comment: When passing $.when() an array like this, it needs to be formatted like this to work.
`$.when.apply(null, XHRs)`

Comment: @Boidy Is that because the signature of `$.when` is expecting an object or list of objects, not an array of objects? I'd have to sift through some old code but I believe I tested this solution.

Comment: @jasper Yes I believe so. Maybe its used has changed slightly in the time since you originally posted this answer. When I used your answer on here to try to fix my own problem, I couldn't get it to work, so I posted the problem again, and using `apply()` was the advice I was given, which worked. In the interest of helping others, I thought I would pass on the advice to this question too. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24306790/how-do-you-use-when-then-to-trigger-a-function-when-using-deffered-objects .

Comment: I can confirm that `apply` is necessary to get the correct results. See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/devuxer/p4t1gs9z/. I edited the answer for those who don't notice the comment thread.

Answer (score 5):

AJAX happens asynchronously, so you'll have to try something like this:

```
var total = $('#tabCurrentFriends > .dragFriend').length;
var completed = 0;

$('#tabCurrentFriends > .dragFriend').each(function(){ 
    var friendId = $(this).data('rowid');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", url: "../../page/newtab.php", data: "action=new&tabname=" + tabname + "&bid=" + brugerid + "&fid=" + friendid,
            complete: function(data){
              completed++;

              if (completed == total) {
                // All have been loaded.
              }
        }
    });
});
```